# Swipe to clear permanent notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a service running with `startForeground` that displays a permanent notification for the user. From time to time the notification displays a status, I want the user to swipe and clear the status, obviously the notification will still be there, is it possible?

Comment: could add a secondary notification for status that is dismissible.  Or add an action button to the permanent one to clear the status (or reset it to the default one)

Comment: @edthethird this are some of the options I am considering now, I will keep looking into this maybe I find a way.